# Yum update or Yum upgrade for nodejs and npm in EC2 server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I am trying to update/upgrade the nodejs and npm packages using "yum" in the EC2 server (Linux 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64).

The current version of nodejs is 0.10.36 and i want it to be upgraded to 0.12.0

Below is the command:

**sudo yum -y upgrade nodejs**

But this does not update/upgrade.

Am I missing something? I also tried updating both nodejs and npm , but no luck.

I also did the following for Linux machines:

**sudo npm install n -g** and then 
**sudo n 0.12.2**

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try nvm instead of n ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre Inglebert. It worked